# Тройной подзапрос PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, postgresql, запрос

Есть небольшая база данных, в ней кусок из трех таблиц

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
    student_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name CHARACTER VARYING(30),
    last_name CHARACTER VARYING(30)
);

CREATE TABLE courses
(
    course_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    course_name CHARACTER VARYING(30),
);

CREATE TABLE students_courses
(
    student_course_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    student_id INTEGER REFERENCES students (student_id),
    course_id INTEGER REFERENCES courses (course_id)
);
```

Мне нужно выводить всех студентов, у которых есть введенный мною курс.
Я пытался сделать это через тройной подзапрос:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM students
WHERE student_id = (SELECT student_id
                    FROM students_courses
                    WHERE course_id =  (SELECT course_id
                                        FROM courses
                                        WHERE course_name = 'Math'));
```

Но мне выдает "ОШИБКА: подзапрос в выражении вернул больше одной строки".
Это происходит уже при выполнении самого "верхнего" запроса, так как при выполнении только 2 внутренних я получаю таблицу с айдишниками студентов, как на скрине [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что проблема в том, что подзапрос возвращает не одно значение, а сразу несколько, но я не могу понять, как можно по другому получить имена студентов.

P.S. Я также понимаю, что проще сделать это через код, занести айди студентов в резалтСет и пройтись по нему, подбирая имена, но хотелось бы понять, как это можно сделать имея лишь консоль СУБД под рукой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте in в подзапросах

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM students
WHERE student_id IN (SELECT student_id
                    FROM students_courses
                    WHERE course_id IN  (SELECT course_id
                                        FROM courses
                                        WHERE course_name = 'Math'));
```

либо по человечески оформить этот запрос

```
SELECT students.first_name, students.last_name
FROM students
INNER JOIN students_courses
    ON students_courses.student_id = students.student_id
INNER JOIN courses
    ON students_courses.course_id = courses.course_id    
WHERE courses.course_name = 'Math';
```